# Menu buttons for a game in Pygame

Tags: python, menu, pygame

I'm trying to use the code below as a menu system which allows me to:

1). Use one button to launch a run code from a separate .py file (that I'll import) [START GAME]

2). Use another button to show a new screen/image of instructions. [INSTRUCTIONS]

3). Use the last button to sys.exit(). [CLOSES GAME]

Any idea how to do this? Code:
http://pastebin.com/B9m6cyj0

Answer (score 0):

I would use [sprites](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite)

1. design a button with paint or something.
2. make a sprite, for every button yo have.
3. with the rect you can set the position on the screen.
4. make 1 additional sprite with size 1x1 for your mouse.
5. check collision between button and mouse sprite with sprite.collide_rect.